# AVPlayerViewController not playing video and showing Quicktime logo

Tags: ios, xcode6, avplayer

I am trying to play video with new AVPlayerViewController introduced in XCode 6.

To play video i have done this setup.

1. Using local mp4 file to play video
2. Extended AVPlayerViewController

**Player setup code :**

```
-(void)setupPlayer
{
    NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"exodus_trailer" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSLog(@"File Path : %@",filePath);
    AVAsset *avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]];
    AVPlayerItem *avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:avAsset];
    self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];
    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];
    [self.player play];
}
```

**KVO handling :**

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self.player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"])
    {
        if (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed)
        {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Failed");
        }
        else if (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay)
        {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");
           [self.player play];
        }
        else if (self.player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown)
        {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue :**

KVO log is printing AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay and file path seems ok. Previously view was at least showing player with all default controls, but now without any changes it started to show Quick time logo without any control. What is meaning of showing this logo ? what i am doing wrong here ?

**Screenshot :**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is exactly like what you wanted to do. The problem with your code is that you are not using file path,  use this to load the file path   **NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString]**

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testfile" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];

    self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [self.player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"
                                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                      context:NULL];

}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self.player) {
        AVPlayerStatus status = [change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
        if (status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            [self.player play];
            [self.player removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status"];
        }
    }
    else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Only mistake was [NSURL URLWithString:filePath], replaced it with [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath],But it is not showing player controls even though i have set self.showsPlaybackControls = YES; Thanks :-)

Comment: @Sandep can you please look into this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919972/hide-quictime-logo-avplayerviewcontrollercontentview-images